# Configuring baretail to show logs over the network

Tags: linux, windows, logging, sftp

I am looking for a log reader that updates in real time. Also, my log files are on a server running Linux, while I'm on a Windows system.

I found [Bare Metal's BareTail](https://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/), which I'm having difficulty configuring. I have written a simple batch to execute & open the log file but it is not able to, which is not very surprising, as the server needs a username/password which I don't know how to specify. My batch:

```
:: Set Path to BareTail.exe Location
set path=path;"D:\Installs"

:: Set Server Path & Folder Path
set server=10.10.10.20
set dir=\product\install\logs\

start baretail.exe \\%server%%dir%system.log
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Linux machine, create an SMB share that points to the `logs` directory.

In Windows Explorer, map the SMB share to a drive letter. In your case, mapping opens the login dialog for the server. Then simply drag the log file into baretail.